# What directory do objects of the File() class look in?

Tags: java, android, file, java-io, aide

I have a project in Aide (for Android) that compiles code that is written in Java.

I would like to check and see if a file on my phone exists and noticed that when I use code that reads the existing file (using 'Istream.open() and Istream.read()' inside a thread), I don't have to specify the current working directory, but when I use File.exists(), I do.

I tried printing System.getProperty("user.dir") and got just a backslash '', but KNOW that the current working directory, is NOT the root directory of my phone.

In the meantime, I tried putting the directory that I THINK all the files that uses the 'File = new 1File(filename)' class are stored in (placing the directories before the filename). I tried things like...

```
project name+"\app\assets\"+filename,
"\"+project name+"\app\assets\"+filename,
project name+"\assets\"+filename,
"\"+project name+"\assets\"+file1name,
```

Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: You have a lot of confusion here.  File objects look at a file on the device it runs on.  Not on your PC.  There is no app or assets directory on the device, those don't come over as files.  Assets are compiled into your apk, which is a single file that has everything in the app.  You don't use File to access an asset, you use AssetManager

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out using the AssetManager class.